# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in import statement

Tags: node.js, express, google-maps-api-3, import

I'm attempting to put my first full-stack application together and am getting an unexpected syntax error:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

The error is coming from this line of code in my map.js file:

```
import {userInput} from './algorithm/searchingAlgorithm.js';
```

ejs file:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/map.js"></script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCx0LvEwPUgGhpLjCErr24dOnk-VWjo83g&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
```

from './algorithm/searchingAlgorithm.js':

```
export default async function userInput(origin, destination){
```

I've done a lot of searching and have yet to come up with an answer.  I'm using node.js/express and express generator, javascript.  I'm also utilizing the google maps api.

Answer (score 0):

The `import` and `export` statements are used frequently in web development, but they do not currently work automatically in a browser because they are newer features in the JavaScript language. You need to "build" the code into a format that the browser can execute. Example code on the web tends to assume that you are already doing this.

There are different tools that allow you to do this, such as [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org) or [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

Comment: Getting webpack to build the code into a format that the browser can execute has been difficult.

I've set up my webpack.config.js file as follows:

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app.js',
  output: {
    filename: './main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  node: {
  fs: 'empty'
  },
  mode:"development",
  externals: ['net']
};

Webpack is creating a main.js file in './dist', however, I'm getting a 404 error from the browser when trying to access the app on localhost  

GET http://localhost:3000/main.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Webpack configs. I think I answered your initial problem, so this sounds like a separate question.

Comment: Let me know how I can improve my question to get rid of the downvote!

Comment: I didn't downvote. Could you accept my answer? I think I answered you're original question.

Answer (score 0):

Heads up for anyone running into this issue like I was.
TLDR; make sure to run the import statement from GLOBAL SCOPE.

I ended up trying to insert my first `import {test_exported_function} from "./test.js";`
from inside of my main function which waits for the DOM content to load before running all of my scripts.

Didn't realize that I needed to execute that line from global scope of the script.
Once I realized that, it suddenly hit me how dumb I was for trying to import from a function scope.
(ﾉ≧ڡ≦) Teehee~!