# Error loading Webpack created bundle in my view when using an Express server: "external_"net":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: net is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

In attempting to serve up my code locally using an express generated server, I encountered the known problem of node.js not recognizing es6 import/export statements.

To solve this problem, [I decided to try bundling my application using webpack.][1]

I'm now having a problem loading the webpack bundle from my .ejs view.

I initially used the default output path of './dist' but received 404 errors when loading my page.

In troubleshooting, I reasoned that the bundle was just like any other static file and so I decided to move the output location to the static folder I specified in my project's entrypoint app.js page.

From app.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

From webpack.config.js

```
"output": {
            "path": path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/javascripts"),
            "filename": "bundle.js"
        },
```

It seems that I was successful in executing the bundle, however, I'm now receiving a different error in the browser when loading my app:

```
external_"net":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: net is not defined
    at eval (external_"net":1)
    at Object.net (bundle.js:3539)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at eval (request.js:18)
    at Object../node_modules/express/lib/request.js (bundle.js:1450)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at eval (express.js:21)
    at Object../node_modules/express/lib/express.js (bundle.js:1414)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at eval (index.js:11)
```

I'm considering scrapping webpack entirely and attacking my original problem of getting node.js to recognize import/export statements some other way but I thought I should, at the very least, do a deep dive first.

Please, let me know if I'm leaving anything out that would make my question easier to understand and more approachable.

Here is the relevant code:

view (index.ejs):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascripts/bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascripts/map.js"></script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCx0LvEwPUgGhpLjCErr24dOnk-VWjo83g&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
```

application entrypoint (app.js):

```
let createError = require('http-errors');
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let logger = require('morgan');
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;


let indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
let usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

let app = express();
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

webpack config file (webpack.config.js):

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    "entry": "./app.js",
    "output": {
        "path": path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/javascripts"),
        "filename": "bundle.js"
    },
    node: {
    fs: 'empty'
    },
    mode:"development",
    externals: ['net'],
    "module": {
        "rules": [
            {
                "test": /\.js$/,
                "exclude": /node_modules/,
                "use": {
                    "loader": "babel-loader",
                    "options": {
                        "presets": [
                            "env"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "test": /\.css$/,
                "use": [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm creating my webpack bundle using the following command in the terminal: "npx webpack --display-error-details --config webpack.config.js"

```
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728772/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-import-statement
```

Comment: external_"net", I believe, is a file created by webpack and contains a one line module.export: module.exports = net;

Comment: for express app with webpack, IMO , you want separate entries for client and server.

Comment: @RobertRowntree - Where can I read up on creating two entries for client and server?  What's the rationale?  What would my webpack.config.js file end up looking like with separate entry points?  Thanks for responding!